# Vue.js component content disappears after 1 second

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm working on a Vue.js project where I have a component that displays chat messages. The problem is that the content of the component disappears after 1 second, and I'm not sure why.

Here's an overview of the component structure:

The parent component retrieves a list of chats from an API and passes it as a prop to the child component.
The child component displays the list of chats in the sidebar and has a main content area where the messages of the selected chat should be displayed.
When a chat is selected, an API call is made to fetch the messages for that chat, and the messages are stored in a messages data property of the child component.
The selected chat is also stored in a selectedChat data property.
The issue is that when I select a chat, the messages briefly appear in the main content area but then disappear after 1 second. I've checked for any code that modifies the selectedChat or messages properties, but I couldn't find any.

I've also verified that the API call to fetch the messages is successful, and the data is being stored in the messages property correctly.

I suspect there might be a reactive update or re-render happening that causes the content to disappear. I've reviewed my code and checked for CSS styles or transitions that could be affecting the visibility, but couldn't find anything obvious.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and figure out why the component content disappears after 1 second?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
const props = defineProps({
    chats: Array
});

const selectedChat = ref(null);
const messages = ref(null);
const chatContainer = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    initializeSelectedChat();
});

const initializeSelectedChat = () => {
    if (props.chats && props.chats.length > 0) {
        selectedChat.value = props.chats[0];
        fetchChatContent(selectedChat.value.id);
    }
};

const selectChat = (chat) => {
    selectedChat.value = chat;
    fetchChatContent(chat.id);
};
```

and its the content part:

```js
        <div class="w-full flex text-white">
            <template v-if="selectedChat">
                <div class="w-full flex h-screen bg-slate-900">
                    <div class="w-full overflow-auto pb-36" ref="chatContainer">
                        <h2>{{ selectedChat.name }}</h2>
                        <template>
                            {{ selectedChat.name }}
                        </template>
                        <Skeleton v-show="false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
```

and its also change part

```js
<template v-for="chat in chats.data" :key="chat.id">
                    <li class='bg-slate-900 px-4 py-2 my-2 flex justify-between font-semibold text-slate-500'>
                        <Link @click="selectChat(chat)">
                            {{ chat.name }}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </template>
```

When a user click on a chatname data loads on content part but disappear after one second.

Comment: Can you share what this function does fetchChatContent(chat.id); ?

Comment: @EdmonBelchev ```const fetchChatContent = async (chatId) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/chats/${chatId}/content`);
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
            messages.value = data.messages;
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to fetch chat content");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch chat content", error);
    }
};```